# How to get subprocess output and maintain encoding

Tags: python, windows, shell, encoding

I am most likely missing some really easy, but I can't wrap my head around why what seems to work for everyone else doesnt work for me.

**Goal:** I want to run shell commands with native output in non-english characters, capture the output in a variable then print to screen.

**Problem:** All my output that should have the non-english characters are replaced with ? marks.

**Thoughts:** is there an encoding issue?  I am running python 3.8, shouldnt be!!  Also running Windows 10, but also happens in Windows 7 and Server 2008.

```
>>> p=subprocess.run("dir",shell=True,encoding="utf8")                     
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A22B-FA10

 Directory of C:\Users\jeronimo\Documents\Github

04/24/2021  08:17 AM    <DIR>          .
04/24/2021  08:17 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/21/2020  09:37 PM    <DIR>          scripts
04/24/2021  08:09 AM    <DIR>          **Администратор**
               1 File(s)            295 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  151,978,950,656 bytes free

>>> p=subprocess.run("dir",capture_output=True,shell=True,encoding="utf8")
>>> p.stdout
' Volume in drive C has no label.\n Volume Serial Number is A22B-FA10\n\n Directory of C:\\Users\\jeronimo\\Documents\\Github\n\n04/24/2021  08:17 AM    <DIR>          .\n04/24/2021  08:17 AM    <DIR>    
      ..\n05/18/2020  01:24 PM scripts\n04/24/2021  08:09 AM    <DIR>          **?????????????**\n               1 File(s)            295 bytes\n              11 Dir(s)  151,976,796,160 bytes free\n'

>>> print(p.stdout)
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A22B-FA10

 Directory of C:\Users\jeronimo\Documents\Github

04/24/2021  08:17 AM    <DIR>          .
04/24/2021  08:17 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/21/2020  09:37 PM    <DIR>          scripts
04/24/2021  08:09 AM    <DIR>          **?????????????**
               1 File(s)            295 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  151,976,796,160 bytes free
```

EDIT: I've tried piping out to a file:

```
>>> f=open('file','a+',encoding='utf-8')                                              
>>> p=subprocess.call("dir",shell=True,encoding="utf8",stdout=f)  
>>> f.close()

Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is A22B-FA10
Directory of C:\Users\jeronimo\Documents\Github
04/24/2021  11:49 AM    <DIR>          .
04/24/2021  11:49 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/21/2020  09:37 PM    <DIR>          scripts
04/24/2021  08:09 AM    <DIR>          ?????????????
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  151,974,350,848 bytes free
```

I've tried many variations of subprocess - popen, run, check_output, call - all give the same result.  What the heck am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's likely that the command you're running is not producing UTF-8 encoded output.  Try using `encoding='mbcs'` instead to get the default Windows locale encoding.

Comment: sadly that didnt change anything :(

Comment: Oh of course, Windows uses a different encoding in its command windows than in ANSI applications.  If you find the appropriate encoding for your version of Windows you can use that instead.  Type `chcp` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved if I change the terminal coding before running subprocess AND specified utf-8 encoding in the subprocess call

```
os.system('chcp 65001')
output = subprocess.run(data, timeout=10, encoding="utf8", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: `chcp 65001` isn't recommended for some reason, evidently there are some bugs in edge cases that Microsoft has never seen fit to fix.

Comment: yea i read it, seems to work so far...any other suggestions instead??  edit: i see your comment, trying...  edit: no change :(

Comment: This sort of worked, but as @MarkRansom said, not optimal

Answer (score 0):

A quick 'module' for this task. *Should* work on any Windows...

I noticed that every windows encoding starts with `cp` and ends with a bunch of numbers. We can get the current encoding writing `chcp` in `cmd.exe`. Go ahead, try this out.

The output should look like this in Russian:

```
Текущая кодовая страница: 866
```

or this (utf-8):

```
Active code page: 65001
```

It will be in the `stdout` of the `subprocess.run` call. We do not care for the letters (and they will be unreadable, since we do not know the encoding), but we will get the numbers with `_REGEX` and store them in a module-wide cache variable `_CP_CODE`.

After this we know the encoding and we'll be using `run` function without any problems. It will always return valid strings inside `stdout` and `stderr`.

```
import subprocess
import re


_CP_CODE = None
_REGEX = re.compile(br".+: (\d+)\s*$")


def get_cp_code():
    stdout = subprocess.run(
        "chcp", shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL
    ).stdout
    result = re.search(_REGEX, stdout)
    if result is None:
        raise ValueError(stdout)
    else:
        return int(result.group(1))


def run(cmd, **kwargs):
    global _CP_CODE
    if _CP_CODE is None:
        _CP_CODE = get_cp_code()
    return subprocess.run(
        cmd,
        shell=True,
        encoding=f'cp{_CP_CODE}',
        **kwargs
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    command = f"TASKKILL /F /PID 12345 /T"
    res = run(command)
    print(res.stderr)
```